# Hadoop : java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

My program looks like

```
public class TopKRecord extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static class MapClass extends Mapper<Text, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void map(Text key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // your map code goes here
            String[] fields = value.toString().split(",");
            String year = fields[1];
            String claims = fields[8];

            if (claims.length() > 0 && (!claims.startsWith("\""))) {
                context.write(new Text(year.toString()), new Text(claims.toString()));
            }
        }
    }
   public int run(String args[]) throws Exception {
        Job job = new Job();
        job.setJarByClass(TopKRecord.class);

        job.setMapperClass(MapClass.class);

        FileInputFormat.setInputPaths(job, new Path(args[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(args[1]));

        job.setJobName("TopKRecord");
        job.setMapOutputValueClass(Text.class);
        job.setNumReduceTasks(0);
        boolean success = job.waitForCompletion(true);
        return success ? 0 : 1;
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
        int ret = ToolRunner.run(new TopKRecord(), args);
        System.exit(ret);
    }
}
```

The data looks like

```
"PATENT","GYEAR","GDATE","APPYEAR","COUNTRY","POSTATE","ASSIGNEE","ASSCODE","CLAIMS","NCLASS","CAT","SUBCAT","CMADE","CRECEIVE","RATIOCIT","GENERAL","ORIGINAL","FWDAPLAG","BCKGTLAG","SELFCTUB","SELFCTLB","SECDUPBD","SECDLWBD"
3070801,1963,1096,,"BE","",,1,,269,6,69,,1,,0,,,,,,,
3070802,1963,1096,,"US","TX",,1,,2,6,63,,0,,,,,,,,,
3070803,1963,1096,,"US","IL",,1,,2,6,63,,9,,0.3704,,,,,,,
3070804,1963,1096,,"US","OH",,1,,2,6,63,,3,,0.6667,,,,,,,
```

On running this program I see the following on console

```
12/08/02 12:43:34 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201208021025_0007_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
    at com.hadoop.programs.TopKRecord$MapClass.map(TopKRecord.java:26)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:144)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:370)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:396)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1121)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

I believe that the Class Types are mapped correctly,
[Class Mapper](http://hadoop.apache.org/common/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/mapreduce/Mapper.html),

Please let me know what is that I am doing wrong here?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

When you read a file with a M/R program, the input key of your mapper should be **the index of the line in the file**, while the input value will be the full line.

So here what's happening is that you're trying to have the line index as a `Text` object which is wrong, and you need an `LongWritable` instead so that Hadoop doesn't complain about type.

Try this instead:

```
public class TopKRecord extends Configured implements Tool {

    public static class MapClass extends Mapper<LongWritable, Text, Text, Text> {

        public void map(LongWritable key, Text value, Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {
            // your map code goes here
            String[] fields = value.toString().split(",");
            String year = fields[1];
            String claims = fields[8];

            if (claims.length() > 0 && (!claims.startsWith("\""))) {
                context.write(new Text(year.toString()), new Text(claims.toString()));
            }
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

Also one thing in your code that you might want to reconsider, you're creating 2 `Text` objects for every record you're processing. You should only create these 2 objects right at the beginning, and then in your mapper just set their values by using the `set` method. This will save you a lot of time if you're processing a decent amount of data.

Answer (score 10):

you need to set input format class

```
job.setInputFormatClass(KeyValueTextInputFormat.class);
job.setOutputFormatClass(TextOutputFormat.class);
```

Comment: good point! this was the error in my case, resolved by setting the InputFormatClass to `SequenceFileInputFormat.class`. This worked when the input of this job was the output of a previous job