# Mahout minhash org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text

Tags: hadoop, mahout, minhash

I am using :

hadoop-1.2.1 and mahout-distribution-0.8

When I try to run HASHMIN method with following command:

```
$MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout org.apache.mahout.clustering.minhash.MinHashDriver -i tce-data/cv.vec -o tce-data/out/cv/minHashDriver/ -ow
```

I get this error:

```
tce@osy-Inspiron-N5110:~$ $MAHOUT_HOME/bin/mahout org.apache.mahout.clustering.minhash.MinHashDriver  -i  tce-data/cv.vec  -o tce-data/out/cv/minHashDriver/ -ow
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

Running on hadoop, using /home/tce/app/hadoop-1.2.1/bin/hadoop and HADOOP_CONF_DIR=
MAHOUT-JOB: /home/tce/app/mahout-distribution-0.8/mahout-examples-0.8-job.jar
Warning: $HADOOP_HOME is deprecated.

13/09/10 18:17:46 WARN driver.MahoutDriver: No org.apache.mahout.clustering.minhash.MinHashDriver.props found on classpath, will use command-line arguments only
13/09/10 18:17:46 INFO common.AbstractJob: Command line arguments: {--endPhase=[2147483647], --hashType=[MURMUR], --input=[tce-data/cv.vec], --keyGroups=[2], --minClusterSize=[10], --minVectorSize=[5], --numHashFunctions=[10], --numReducers=[2], --output=[tce-data/out/cv/minHashDriver/], --overwrite=null, --startPhase=[0], --tempDir=[temp], --vectorDimensionToHash=[value]}
13/09/10 18:17:48 INFO input.FileInputFormat: Total input paths to process : 1
13/09/10 18:17:50 INFO mapred.JobClient: Running job: job_201309101645_0031
13/09/10 18:17:51 INFO mapred.JobClient:  map 0% reduce 0%
13/09/10 18:18:27 INFO mapred.JobClient: Task Id : attempt_201309101645_0031_m_000000_0, Status : FAILED
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.hadoop.io.LongWritable cannot be cast to org.apache.hadoop.io.Text
    at org.apache.mahout.clustering.minhash.MinHashMapper.map(MinHashMapper.java:30)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Mapper.run(Mapper.java:145)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.runNewMapper(MapTask.java:764)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.MapTask.run(MapTask.java:364)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child$4.run(Child.java:255)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:415)
    at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1190)
    at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.Child.main(Child.java:249)
```

I appreciate any idea

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14922087/hadoop-longwritable-cannot-be-cast-to-org-apache-hadoop-io-intwritable
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11784729/hadoop-java-lang-classcastexception-org-apache-hadoop-io-longwritable-cannot

Comment: Thank you @Sandip but by now I do not have custom programming, I am only following examples, maybe can be a problem with versions.

Answer (score 0):

Then cross check few things, Your `job.setOutputKeyClass`, `job.setOutputValueClass`, j`ob.setMapOutputKeyClass` and `job.setMapOutputValueClass` should match with reducer key, reducer value, mapper key and mapper value class respectively.

Your stacktrace says there is mismatch in `Mapper`. Your `MinHashMapper` should extend `Mapper<[A, B, C, D >]` where `C` and `D` be same as `job.setMapOutputKeyClass(C)` and `job.setMapOutputValueClass(D)`